# minimize runtime for numpy array manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science

I have an 2 dimensional array with `np.shape(input)=(a,b)` and that looks like

`input=array[array_1[0,0,0,1,0,1,2,0,3,3,2,...,entry_b],...array_a[1,0,0,1,2,2,0,3,1,3,3,...,entry_b]]`

Now I want to create an array `np.shape(output)=(a,b,b)` in which every entry that had the same value in the input get the value 1 and 0 otherwise

for example:

```
input=[[1,0,0,0,1,2]]

output=[array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
               [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
               [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
               [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
               [1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
               [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])]
```

My code so far is looking like:

```
def get_matrix(svdata,padding_size):
List=[]
for k in svdata:
    matrix=np.zeros((padding_size,padding_size))
    for l in range(padding_size):
        for m in range(padding_size):
            if k[l]==k[m]:
                matrix[l][m]=1
    List.append(matrix)
return List
```

But it takes 2:30 min for an input array of shape (2000,256). How can I become more effiecient by using built in numpy solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create the array `y` where `y[i,j,k]` is `1` if `input[i,j] == input[i, k]`.  At least that's what I think you're trying to do.

So `y = input[:,:,None] == input[:,None,:]` will give you a boolean array. You can then convert that to `np.dtype('float64')` using `astype(...)` if you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
res = input[:,:,None]==input[:,None,:]
```

Should give boolean (a,b,b) array

```
res = res.astype(int)
```

to get a 0/1 array

Comment: This seems not to work for my case. I looked up and the shape of my input is (2000,256,1) could this be the problem? where as a=2000 and b=256

Comment: Yes, my answer is based on the original claim that it is (a,b) shape.  WIth the `None`, the 2 shapes become (a,b,1) and (a,1,b) which broadcast together to (a,b,b).  So what do you want to do with the trailing size one?  You could leave it in one, and swap axes in the  other.

Comment: Hey, I used np.squeeze() to get rid of the unwanted dimension and it works now like intended. Thank you for your help!